# undefined reference to `wcstof'

Tags: c++, linker, g++, mingw, wstring

I have a simple program that compiles fine but fails to link due to my passing a wide string to `std::stof`. If I pass a standard non-wide string to `stof`, the program compiles and links with no issues.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace std;

    float f = stof(wstring(L"53.42"));
    cout << f;

    return 0;
}
```

`` c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6636: undefined reference to `wcstof' ``

I'm compiling with mingw 9.2.0 and have tried linking mingwex manually, but doing so doesn't make a difference. `g++ main.cpp -lmingwex`

What is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you add `#include <cwchar>`? Not sure that you should need to, but maybe your compiler/linker is a bit brain-damaged.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make a difference. The error message is the same.